# Setting a reminder in the background of an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, locationmanager, ekeventstore

I am trying to create a reminder when a user enters a region. The code works for creating a reminder when the app is open. But when I call the same code when the app is in the background I get fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. The code below is being called in the AppDelegate.

```
var eventStore: EKEventStore!
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
                let reminder = EKReminder(eventStore: self.eventStore) //This is where I get the error 
                let date = NSDate()
                reminder.title = "Do you have your bags?"
                let dueDateComponents = dateComponentFromNSDate(date.dateByAddingTimeInterval(Double(secondReminderStores) * 60.0))
                reminder.dueDateComponents = dueDateComponents
                reminder.calendar = self.eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()
                do {
                    try self.eventStore.saveReminder(reminder, commit: true)
                }catch{
                    print("Error creating and saving new reminder : \(error)")
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
var eventStore: EKEventStore!
```

...creates the `eventStore` variable (property) and sets its type, but does not actually assign any EKEventStore instance value to it. Thus `eventStore` is `nil`, because that is the default value for any uninitialized Optional. You have shown no *other* code that ever assigned any EKEventStore instance value to it. Thus it is *still* `nil` when this line comes along:

```
let reminder = EKReminder(eventStore: self.eventStore)
```

...and so you crash. All perfectly nice and neat and logical.